# How to properly build a private Go project?

Tags: docker, go, github

I have a Go project, which is a private repo on GitHub. I want to build this project from source. I've tried running `go get -d -v ./... && go install -v ./...` to install all dependencies, but this is the error I got `fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled` which means that it tried to clone my project from GitHub rather than building it from source.

I can really use some help in properly building a Go project from source, with all the dependencies installed. I am using Docker and this is how my `Dockerfile` looks:

```
#build stage
FROM golang:alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /go/src/app
COPY . .
RUN apk add --no-cache git
RUN go get -d -v ./...
RUN go install -v ./...

#final stage
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates
COPY --from=builder /go/bin/app /app
ENTRYPOINT ./app
EXPOSE 8080
```

Only my project's code is private, all other dependencies I have are publically available e.g. `mux`. I have no problem if Go pulls those files from GitHub, but I want to compile my project's code from source.

Comment: Are you using gomod ? What the structure of your project?

Comment: No, I'm not using `gomod`. It's a very simple REST API. I've just started the project. The problem is that when I'm importing my project's own packages, `go compiler` thinks that these are dependencies and tries to fetch them from GitHub. It is a monolithic codebase, with code divided into packages.

Comment: I assume you should use `go build` instead of `go install`.

Comment: The problem isn't with `go install`. The problem is with `go get ./...`, which gets all the dependencies automatically. I think an alternative to this is installing each and every dependency individually.

Comment: If you vendor your dependencies, as you should, you can omit the `go get` step of your build.